# Dealing with queues and test cases for queues

Tags: racket

Hello Im trying to understand what exactly is wrong with mo program. I have written code for enqueue, dequeue, top and size for queues in racket. I have also written test cases to try out my program within the module. When i try to run the test cases by typing out the following command "racket run-tests.rkt | less", i get the following error:
"
default-load-handler: expected only a `module' declaration for`queue', but found an extra expression in: #

=== context ===
default-load/use-compiled
"

Here are my three files and the code within them

1- queue.rkt

```
(module queue racket
  (provide make-queue enqueue dequeue top size queue-tests)
  (struct queue (front back size) #:mutable #:transparent)

    (define (make-queue) (queue null null 0))

(define (enqueue q elt)
    (set-queue-back! q (cons elt (queue-back q)))
    (set-queue-size! q (+ (queue-size q) 1))
    )
(define (dequeue q)
    (cond  ((eq? (queue-size q) 0) null)
           ((null? (queue-front q))
            (begin
              (set-queue-front! q (cdr (reverse (queue-back q))))
              (set-queue-back! q null)
              (set-queue-size! q (- (queue-size q) 1))))
           (else
            (begin
              (set-queue-front! q (cdr (queue-front q)))
              (set-queue-size! q (- (queue-size q) 1))))
           )
  )

  (define (top q)
    (cond ((eq? (queue-size q) 0) null)
          ((null? (queue-front q)) (last (queue-back q)))
          (else (car (queue-front q)))))

   (define (size q)
    (queue-size q))

  ; Test cases Here
  (include "test-queue.rkt")
)
```

2-  test-queue.rkt

```
 #lang racket/base

 (require rackunit)

 (define queue-tests
  (test-suite
    "Tests for the Queue"

    (test-case "Initial Queue Properties"
    (let  ((q (make-queue)))
      (check-equal? (size q) 0 "Queue initially should have size zero.")
      (check-equal? (dequeue q) null "Dequeue on an empty queue returns null")
      (check-equal? (size q) 0 "Dequeue on empty queue leaves size as zero")
      ))

    (test-case "One Element queue ---- Functional test"
       (let ((q (make-queue)))
         (check-equal? (size q) 0 "Stack initially should be of size zero")
         (enqueue q 1)
         (check-equal? (size q) 1 "Added one element to back of queue")
         (check-equal? (top q) 1 "Take a sneak peak at our first element")
         (dequeue q)
         (check-equal? (size 1) 0 "size should now be zero")
         (check-equal? (dequeue q) null "dequeue on empty queue returns null")
         ))

    (test-case "One Element queue --- Internal Test"
       (let  ((q (make-queue)))
         (check-equal? (size q) 0 "queue initially should have size zero.")
         (enqueue q 3)
         (check-equal? (size q) 1 "Added one element.")
         (check-equal? (queue-back q) '(3) "Is the element in the back list?")
         (check-equal? (top s) 3 "Look at our one element.")
         (check-equal? (queue-front q) '(3) "Is the element in the front list?")
         (dequeue s)
         (check-equal? (queue-front q) '() "Is the data empty now?")
         ))

    (test-case "Multi Element queue --- Functional Test"
    (let  ((q (make-queue))
           (elts (list 8 6 7 5 3 0 9))
           )
      (check-equal? (size q) 0 "queue initially should have size zero.")
      (for ((i elts)
            (num (in-range 1 8)))
           (enqueue q i)
           (check-equal? (size q) num "Testing size.")
           (check-equal? (top q) i "Testing top with multiple additions.")
           )
      (for ((i (reverse elts))
            (num (reverse (stream->list (in-range 1 8)))))
           (check-equal? (top q) i "Testing top with multiple deletions")
           (dequeue q)
           (check-equal? (size q) (- num 1) "Testing size.")
           )
      ))

    (test-case "Multi Element queue --- Ebb and Flow Test"
       (let  ((q (make-queue))
              (elts (list 8 6 7 5 3 0 9))
              )
         (check-equal? (size q) 0 "queue initially should have size zero.")
         (for ((i elts)
           (num (in-range 1 8)))
              (enqueue q i)
              (check-equal? (size q) num "Testing size, first flow.")
              (check-equal? (top q) i "Testing top with multiple additions.")
           )
         (for ((i (reverse elts))
               (num (reverse (stream->list (in-range 1 8)))))
              (check-equal? (top q) i "Testing top with multiple deletions")
              (dequeue q)
              (check-equal? (size q) (- num 1) "Testing size, first ebb.")
           )
         (for ((i elts)
               (num (in-range 1 8)))
               (enqueue q i)
               (check-equal? (size q) num "Testing size, second flow.")
               (check-equal? (top q) i "Testing top with multiple additions.")
           )
         (for ((i (reverse elts))
               (num (reverse (stream->list (in-range 1 8)))))
               (check-equal? (top q) i "Testing top with multiple deletions")
               (dequeue q)
               (check-equal? (size q) (- num 1) "Testing size, second ebb.")
           )
      ))

   (test-case "Multi Element queue --- Internal Test"
    (let  ((q (make-queue))
           (elts (list 5 8 8 2 3 0 0))
           (tmp null)
           )
      (for ((i elts)
            (num (in-range 1 8)))
           (enqueue q i)
           (check-equal? (size q) num "Testing size, second flow.")
           (set! tmp (cons i tmp)) ; "push" element to a list
           (check-equal? (queue-front q) tmp "Queue data is in correct form.")
           )
      ))

    ))
```

3- run-tests.rkt

```
#lang racket/base

(require "queue.rkt")

(require rackunit/text-ui)

(run-tests queue-tests)
```

Any kind of help in spotting the bug present would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who's class is this for?

Comment: its for cs 331 data structures and algorithms

Answer (score 4):

The error you're referring to could be caused, I believe, by having the language level set incorrectly in your "queue.rkt" file.  In particular, the language for all three of these should be set to

"Use Language Declared in Source".

Honestly, I'm really not sure why you're building this as three separate modules; I think it's causing you additional difficulty, but it should certainly be possible to do it this way.

Edit: looks like you have paren problems.  In particular, you have three close-parens after your definition of 'size'.  Does DrRacket not highlight this problem for you when you run?

Edit 2: ooh, yucky: you're using "include". Don't use include.

Edit 3: Okay, here: I reformatted your code to be in one file:

```
(module queue racket

  (require rackunit)

  (provide make-queue enqueue dequeue top size)
  (struct queue (front back size) #:mutable #:transparent)

  (define (make-queue) (queue null null 0))

  (define (enqueue q elt)
    (set-queue-back! q (cons elt (queue-back q)))
    (set-queue-size! q (+ (queue-size q) 1))
    )
  (define (dequeue q)
    (cond  ((eq? (queue-size q) 0) null)
           ((null? (queue-front q))
            (begin
              (set-queue-front! q (cdr (reverse (queue-back q))))
              (set-queue-back! q null)
              (set-queue-size! q (- (queue-size q) 1))))
           (else
            (begin
              (set-queue-front! q (cdr (queue-front q)))
              (set-queue-size! q (- (queue-size q) 1))))
           )
    )

  (define (top q)
    (cond ((eq? (queue-size q) 0) null)
          ((null? (queue-front q)) (last (queue-back q)))
          (else (car (queue-front q)))))

  (define (size q)
    (queue-size q))

  (test-case "Initial Queue Properties"
             (let  ((q (make-queue)))
               (check-equal? (size q) 0 "Queue initially should have size zero.")
               (check-equal? (dequeue q) null "Dequeue on an empty queue returns null")
               (check-equal? (size q) 0 "Dequeue on empty queue leaves size as zero")
               ))

  (test-case "One Element queue ---- Functional test"
             (let ((q (make-queue)))
               (check-equal? (size q) 0 "Stack initially should be of size zero")
               (enqueue q 1)
               (check-equal? (size q) 1 "Added one element to back of queue")
               (check-equal? (top q) 1 "Take a sneak peak at our first element")
               (dequeue q)
               (check-equal? (size 1) 0 "size should now be zero")
               (check-equal? (dequeue q) null "dequeue on empty queue returns null")
               ))

  #;(test-case "One Element queue --- Internal Test"
             (let  ((q (make-queue)))
               (check-equal? (size q) 0 "queue initially should have size zero.")
               (enqueue q 3)
               (check-equal? (size q) 1 "Added one element.")
               (check-equal? (queue-back q) '(3) "Is the element in the back list?")
               (check-equal? (top s) 3 "Look at our one element.")
               (check-equal? (queue-front q) '(3) "Is the element in the front list?")
               (dequeue s)
               (check-equal? (queue-front q) '() "Is the data empty now?")
               ))

  (test-case "Multi Element queue --- Functional Test"
             (let  ((q (make-queue))
                    (elts (list 8 6 7 5 3 0 9))
                    )
               (check-equal? (size q) 0 "queue initially should have size zero.")
               (for ((i elts)
                     (num (in-range 1 8)))
                 (enqueue q i)
                 (check-equal? (size q) num "Testing size.")
                 (check-equal? (top q) i "Testing top with multiple additions.")
                 )
               (for ((i (reverse elts))
                     (num (reverse (stream->list (in-range 1 8)))))
                 (check-equal? (top q) i "Testing top with multiple deletions")
                 (dequeue q)
                 (check-equal? (size q) (- num 1) "Testing size.")
                 )
               ))

  (test-case "Multi Element queue --- Ebb and Flow Test"
             (let  ((q (make-queue))
                    (elts (list 8 6 7 5 3 0 9))
                    )
               (check-equal? (size q) 0 "queue initially should have size zero.")
               (for ((i elts)
                     (num (in-range 1 8)))
                 (enqueue q i)
                 (check-equal? (size q) num "Testing size, first flow.")
                 (check-equal? (top q) i "Testing top with multiple additions.")
                 )
               (for ((i (reverse elts))
                     (num (reverse (stream->list (in-range 1 8)))))
                 (check-equal? (top q) i "Testing top with multiple deletions")
                 (dequeue q)
                 (check-equal? (size q) (- num 1) "Testing size, first ebb.")
                 )
               (for ((i elts)
                     (num (in-range 1 8)))
                 (enqueue q i)
                 (check-equal? (size q) num "Testing size, second flow.")
                 (check-equal? (top q) i "Testing top with multiple additions.")
                 )
               (for ((i (reverse elts))
                     (num (reverse (stream->list (in-range 1 8)))))
                 (check-equal? (top q) i "Testing top with multiple deletions")
                 (dequeue q)
                 (check-equal? (size q) (- num 1) "Testing size, second ebb.")
                 )
               ))

  (test-case "Multi Element queue --- Internal Test"
             (let  ((q (make-queue))
                    (elts (list 5 8 8 2 3 0 0))
                    (tmp null)
                    )
               (for ((i elts)
                     (num (in-range 1 8)))
                 (enqueue q i)
                 (check-equal? (size q) num "Testing size, second flow.")
                 (set! tmp (cons i tmp)) ; "push" element to a list
                 (check-equal? (queue-front q) tmp "Queue data is in correct form.")
                 )
               ))



  )
```

When I run this code, I get a pretty straightforward error in one of your test cases.

More generally, I'm taken aback that you would write this much test code without running it :). I would personally have written one small test case and then tried it out, rather than doing all of that work before discovering a more fundamental problem. I admire your tenacity, but I think you need a bit more paranoia :)

Let me know if you have more trouble.

EDIT: splitting into two files, per your request.

File 1: queue.rkt

```
(module queue racket

  (provide make-queue enqueue dequeue top size)
  (struct queue (front back size) #:mutable #:transparent)

  (define (make-queue) (queue null null 0))

  (define (enqueue q elt)
    (set-queue-back! q (cons elt (queue-back q)))
    (set-queue-size! q (+ (queue-size q) 1)))

  (define (dequeue q)
    (cond  ((eq? (queue-size q) 0) null)
           ((null? (queue-front q))
            (begin
              (set-queue-front! q (cdr (reverse (queue-back q))))
              (set-queue-back! q null)
              (set-queue-size! q (- (queue-size q) 1))))
           (else
            (begin
              (set-queue-front! q (cdr (queue-front q)))
              (set-queue-size! q (- (queue-size q) 1))))))

  (define (top q)
    (cond ((eq? (queue-size q) 0) null)
          ((null? (queue-front q)) (last (queue-back q)))
          (else (car (queue-front q)))))

  (define (size q)
    (queue-size q))

  )
```

File 2: queue-tests.rkt, in the same dir:

```
(module test-queue racket

  (require "queue.rkt"
           rackunit)


  (test-case "Initial Queue Properties"
             (let  ((q (make-queue)))
               (check-equal? (size q) 0 "Queue initially should have size zero.")
               (check-equal? (dequeue q) null "Dequeue on an empty queue returns null")
               (check-equal? (size q) 0 "Dequeue on empty queue leaves size as zero")
               ))

  (test-case "One Element queue ---- Functional test"
             (let ((q (make-queue)))
               (check-equal? (size q) 0 "Stack initially should be of size zero")
               (enqueue q 1)
               (check-equal? (size q) 1 "Added one element to back of queue")
               (check-equal? (top q) 1 "Take a sneak peak at our first element")
               (dequeue q)
               (check-equal? (size 1) 0 "size should now be zero")
               (check-equal? (dequeue q) null "dequeue on empty queue returns null")
               ))

  (test-case "One Element queue --- Internal Test"
             (let  ((q (make-queue)))
               (check-equal? (size q) 0 "queue initially should have size zero.")
               (enqueue q 3)
               (check-equal? (size q) 1 "Added one element.")
               (check-equal? (queue-back q) '(3) "Is the element in the back list?")
               (check-equal? (top s) 3 "Look at our one element.")
               (check-equal? (queue-front q) '(3) "Is the element in the front list?")
               (dequeue s)
               (check-equal? (queue-front q) '() "Is the data empty now?")
               ))

  (test-case "Multi Element queue --- Functional Test"
             (let  ((q (make-queue))
                    (elts (list 8 6 7 5 3 0 9))
                    )
               (check-equal? (size q) 0 "queue initially should have size zero.")
               (for ((i elts)
                     (num (in-range 1 8)))
                 (enqueue q i)
                 (check-equal? (size q) num "Testing size.")
                 (check-equal? (top q) i "Testing top with multiple additions.")
                 )
               (for ((i (reverse elts))
                     (num (reverse (stream->list (in-range 1 8)))))
                 (check-equal? (top q) i "Testing top with multiple deletions")
                 (dequeue q)
                 (check-equal? (size q) (- num 1) "Testing size.")
                 )
               ))

  (test-case "Multi Element queue --- Ebb and Flow Test"
             (let  ((q (make-queue))
                    (elts (list 8 6 7 5 3 0 9))
                    )
               (check-equal? (size q) 0 "queue initially should have size zero.")
               (for ((i elts)
                     (num (in-range 1 8)))
                 (enqueue q i)
                 (check-equal? (size q) num "Testing size, first flow.")
                 (check-equal? (top q) i "Testing top with multiple additions.")
                 )
               (for ((i (reverse elts))
                     (num (reverse (stream->list (in-range 1 8)))))
                 (check-equal? (top q) i "Testing top with multiple deletions")
                 (dequeue q)
                 (check-equal? (size q) (- num 1) "Testing size, first ebb.")
                 )
               (for ((i elts)
                     (num (in-range 1 8)))
                 (enqueue q i)
                 (check-equal? (size q) num "Testing size, second flow.")
                 (check-equal? (top q) i "Testing top with multiple additions.")
                 )
               (for ((i (reverse elts))
                     (num (reverse (stream->list (in-range 1 8)))))
                 (check-equal? (top q) i "Testing top with multiple deletions")
                 (dequeue q)
                 (check-equal? (size q) (- num 1) "Testing size, second ebb.")
                 )
               ))

  (test-case "Multi Element queue --- Internal Test"
             (let  ((q (make-queue))
                    (elts (list 5 8 8 2 3 0 0))
                    (tmp null)
                    )
               (for ((i elts)
                     (num (in-range 1 8)))
                 (enqueue q i)
                 (check-equal? (size q) num "Testing size, second flow.")
                 (set! tmp (cons i tmp)) ; "push" element to a list
                 (check-equal? (queue-front q) tmp "Queue data is in correct form.")
                 )
               )))
```

Comment: oK so i have deleted the extra paran after the size declaration so that last parens (after the include "test-queue.rkt"). I am now getting standard test run errors. I have a question though, why do you  take out the "include...." Im trying to run the program test case based on how my professor taught my class to do so but using stacks instead of queues. that is why i have three files. Did you remove the include because you wanted to run the code directly from say an ide like DrRacket?

Comment: There are two separate questions here: when should you split your program into multiple files, and what mechanism should you use to do so? Oops... separate comment coming.

Comment: In answer to the first question: I generally keep the tests in the file with the code until it grows to several hundred lines; it's just easier for me than popping back and forth between buffers, and I get better highlighting and arrows. That's a matter of personal preference. In answer to the second question, you should definitely use "require" rather than "include". The "require" mechanism gives you much better modularization, and cleaner separation. In this case, then, you'd "require" your queue implementation in your test case module. I can rewrite the code in that way, if you want.

Comment: yeah please would you mind doing so if its not of any inconvenience? im eager to learn several ways of implementing the code.